# VBA Macro to Merge Cells based on Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge cells in excel using VBA based on the column value. For instance, on row one, wherever the month is the same, merge those cells. I've tried the following code :

```
Sub Main()

Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To 13
        If StrComp(Cells(1, j), Cells(1, j + 1), vbTextCompare) Then
            Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(1, j + 1)).Merge
        End If

    Next j

End Sub
```

Here, I'm keeping the row fixed as the first row and iterating over the columns and checking if the next cell value is same as the current value. However, in the output it's merging incorrect cells. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier to understand.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 13 To 2 Step -1 'Loop from the last cell, and stop at the second column 
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = .Cells(1, i).Offset(, -1).Value Then
                .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(1, i).Offset(, -1)).Merge
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: But worth to mention it is significantly slower (it merges more often than needed) and it has a useless `With` statement (none of your statemets within uses the `With`).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  First, I think you are one of the best coders on this site and you provide astute  answers that help people. I'm not trying to disparage your answer, just providing an alternate example. Yes, it does merge more often, but it is easier to understand and I don't think that the speed is a factor when dealing with the small range in the OPs question. Thank you for pointing out that I did not connect the worksheet focus properly,  I try to always set the worksheet, because I've seen too many errors when the worksheet is not identified properly. I've updated my code. Thank you

Comment: Just not to be misunderstood. My comment wasn't meant to discredit your answer. It's always good to see alternatives (and I always give my points for them). But I think it is also worthy to know the differences between the given solutions. So the pro *"easier to understand"* comes with the con *"slower"*. Of course speed is not always a relevant factor but if any future reader (with a similar issue but different amount of data) reads it and knows what's the difference he/she can wisley choose the appropiate answer for his/her needs.

Answer (score 2):

Should work like this …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MergeSameValuesInRow()
    Const iRow As Long = 1         'the row number
    Const FirstColumn As Long = 1  'first column with data in iRow

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'define your worksheet

    Dim LastColumn As Long  'find last used column in iRow
    LastColumn = ws.Cells(iRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim StartCell As Range  'remember the start cell (first occurence of a new value)
    Set StartCell = ws.Cells(iRow, FirstColumn)

    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = FirstColumn + 1 To LastColumn + 1  'loop through columns in iRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> StartCell.Value Then  'if value changed …
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False  'hide merging messages
            ws.Range(StartCell, ws.Cells(iRow, iCol - 1)).Merge  'merge from start cell until one before value change
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            Set StartCell = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)  'set start cell to the next value
        End If
    Next iCol
End Sub
```

It will change this …
[image]

into this …
[image]

Comment: I've accepted GMalc answer as it's short and consice. But, your answer is appreciated!